# Discord Clear Command

Tags: discord, discord.py

Trying to get the bot to clear message after waited time but i can't seem to figure out why.

It waits but then doesn't clear the bots message, i think I've got the wrong variable but I'm not sure what it is.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount = 5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
    await ctx.send("Cleared " + str(amount) + " messages")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: `send()` returns a `Message` object which then you can delete. Also use `asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()` as to not block your bot from doing other things.

Comment: You can use the delete_after argument of send

Answer (score 0):

Your command should be like this. Use `asyncio` library

```
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
await asyncio.sleep(your_time)
await ctx.send("Done ", hidden=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd wanna use something like this. It's a basic clear command.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amout : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amout)
```